# not able to render html with node server

Tags: node.js, server

I am trying to render an html file using a node server.  However I am getting the following error.

```
sh: ./server.js: Permission denied
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 126
npm ERR! rock-paper-scissors@1.0.0 start: `./server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the rock-paper-scissors@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to 
install?
```

I have run npm install to install any dependencies which there are none.  The code I have written the following code in the server.js . I think it is pointing to the index.html file.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

function onRequest(request, response) {
response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
fs.readFile('./index.html', null, function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
        response.writeHead(404);
        response.write('File not found');
    } else {
        response.write(data);
    }
    response.end();
  });

 }

 http.createServer(onRequest).listen(3000);
```

Any help would be appreciated to get this server up and running.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize it but the server was running when I typed node server.js . Just that I didn't console log a message to say that it was.  It is just showing the html and I need to figure out why it is not showing me the css styling and the JavaScript.